# Compute log(x - y) given log(x) and log(y), without overflows?

Tags: c++, floating-point, numeric, logarithm

The following function computes `log(x + y)` given the values of `log(x)` and `log(y)`, avoiding overflows or underflows if `x` or `y` are very large or very small:

```
double log_add(double logx, double logy)
{
    return max(logx, logy) + log1p(exp(-fabs(logx - logy)));
}
```

There must be an analogous `log_sub` function to compute `log(x - y)`. What is it?

More generally, I need to compute `log(x - y - z)` given `log(x)`, `log(y)` and `log(z)`. From `log_add` and `log_sub` I can compute `log(x - y - z)` in two steps, but maybe there is an optimal way?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Nope. You're negating the logarithm of `y`, not `y` itself.

Comment: oops misread that the values are logs

Answer (score 2):

Why not just go straight from the [identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Summation.2Fsubtraction):

```
double log_add(double logx, double logy) {
    return logx + log1p(exp(logy - logx));
}

double log_sub(double logx, double logy) {
    return logx + log1p(-exp(logy - logx));
}
```

For your specific case:

```
// log(x - y - z) given the three logs
double log_xyz(double logx, double logy, double logz) {
    return logx + log1p(-exp(logy - logx) - exp(logz - logx));
}
```

Comment: Due to the presence of calls to `exp()`, it seems to me that the code runs a real risk of overflow. E.g. `logy = 708`, `logx = -3`, will cause overflow in IEEE-754 double-precision arithmetic.

Comment: @njuffa I'm just providing the identities :) These are they.

Comment: See http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/vignettes/log1mexp-note.pdf for details on log1pexp

Comment: Unfortunately, CRAN seems to be down at the moment, try http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/web/packages/Rmpfr/vignettes/log1mexp-note.pdf

Comment: @njuffa I presume that this code is intended to be invoked with logx > logy, but in this case we get a serious chance to run into underflow :)

Comment: It would be helpful if you would state your assumptions on the relative sizes of x,y,z and/or logx,logy,logz in all your functions.  I have sort of convinced myself that there is *some* set of assumptions such that your answer is correct and useful, but it's hard to tell.